# cURL Upload/Download Speed Test

Tags: linux, curl

What is speed measure method to upload and download ?
**What options do I have to give to know the speed (MB/s) ?**

```
curl -H 'X-Auth-Token:8xxx'
http://x.x.x.x:8080/v1/AUTH_90xxxxxfccf7c/speed_test/ --upload-file
test05.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973056/curl-how-to-display-progress-information-while-uploading be helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the output somewhere. Use `> /dev/null` or `-o file` or `-O` or similar. That will make the [progress meter](https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/progressmeter) show.